# RegEx SQL, combine known pattern with variable numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to check whether there is a known pattern with variable numbers.

This column 'shortcut' has values like this

```
|shortcuts|
-----------
|ab1
|ab2
|ab23
|abc123
```

The only thing I've got for my SQL-statement is the alphabetical pattern e.g. 'ab'

So I started with

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE shortcut LIKE 'ab%'
```

I only need ab1, ab2 and ab23 and NOT abc12.

Is there a way to modify my statement? There is at least one number, numbers always follow the known pattern and the pattern is the only known value.

Comment: Sorry, does it mean you want to also return records like `ab12 some text here`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
where shortcut regexp '^ab[0-9]+'
```

This says that `shortcut` starts with "ab" and is followed by at least one digit.

Comment: Thank you very much, this statement did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE shortcut REGEXP '^ab[0-9]+$'
```

The `^ab[0-9]+$` regex (see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/zOQZez/2)) matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `ab` - an `ab` string (case insensitively, use `BINARY` after `REGEXP` to make it case sensitive)
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

See this [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Eab%5B0-9%5D%2B%24):

[image]